# SQL In-Memory OLTP function and requirements

Tags: sql-server, in-memory-database

All new to StackOverflow

I only have a decent amount of SQL knowledge, why is why I am reaching out here.

Currently handling a Msql16 > Msql19 migration, and considering implementing In-Memory.

When I Google around, it seems In-Memory is a Checkbox pr. Database, which activates In-Memory?

Is In-Memory Application dependent?

Does a developer have to program the application to actually benefit from In-Memory?

OR can ONE simply activate In-Memory, and then it works?

Please feel free to add any missing information to my questions...
Thanks in advance.
Br
CHER

Comment: All of the questions are based on invalid assumptions. Databases aggressively cache data in memory already. In-Memory tables were already available in SQL Server 2014, so if the existing database didn't use them, there was a reason. The benefit you get from them is improved concurrency due to the different locking mechanisms, not a speed up due to memory caching. Precisely because the data was *already* cached

Comment: Why do you want to use in-memory tables in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve? In-memory tables won't make bad queries go faster or cover up for missing indexes, they'll eat up memory that could be used to serve other queries.

Comment: With In-Memory, I want to take into account any Latency challenges in our Shared infrastructure.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. Beyond query execution time, latency occurs *outside* the database. Once you execute a query the results are cached anyway, so executing the query again will use the cached data

Comment: If you want to reduce network overhead you should reduce the number of queries, eg by caching locally, or batching queries. Retrieving 100 items one by one has 100x larger overhead than executing a query that returns all 100 rows

Comment: Just be really clear. In-memory is a different architecture. Enabling it doesn't do anything. You have to then create specific in-memory data structures. There are limitations on these structures and differences in behavior between them and standard structures. I'd strongly suggest a lot more research before you turn this on. Also, know this, once you turn it on on a give database, it's on forever, so be sure.